# Set up Trello notifications to email you when task or event is due

Tags: trello, notifications

Can Trello notifications be used as task or event reminders? Can you use Trello for active scheduling?

As far as I can see you can enter the due date "due mm/dd/yy" but thats it! You have to look through your cards to notice what is due or overdue.

Comment: Am going to understand your question as wanting to be emailed when a card is due or past due

Answer (score 4):

The [Trello Glossary](https://trello.com/glossary) currently says, for Due Dates:

> You can add or change a due date for a card by entering 'due mm/dd/[yy]yy' as a comment. A badge with the due date will appear on cards. A yellow badge means it's due tomorrow. A red badge means it's past due.

So, at least the overdue ones should stand out.

The [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) currently has several items relating to future improvements in Due dates.

- [Due Dates v2](https://trello.com/card/board/due-dates-v2/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4db03961c9fd63357d0531b7)
- [Due dates not working properly](https://trello.com/card/board/due-dates-not-working-properly/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e72b65c49253ab114135ed1)

**Edit - 06/10/2011**

I see that Trello have announced the implementation of [Due Dates](https://trello.com/card/board/due-dates-v2/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4db03961c9fd63357d0531b7):

> In Due Dates v1, you could add a due date to a card by making a comment that says something like "Due 2011-12-04"
>
> In Due Dates v2 (which has now been implemented), you can add due dates using an "Add Due Date" button. You'll also be able to add a due time. You can also remove due dates, and the "Is this item due soon/past due" logic has been improved.
>
> We'll add notifications for upcoming due dates in a future version (Due Dates v3)

This is due for release in the next day or two, according to their Twitter account.

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer feature available as of October 2012.

> Today we’re announcing the release of due date notifications. When a card you are subscribed to is 24 hours away from being due, you’ll get a notification in the app and via email. We think this makes due dates even more useful for those folks that rely on them. Hope you love it!

Here is the [Trello Blog entry 'Due Date Notifications...'](http://blog.trello.com/due-date-notifications-list-move-and-copy-org-logos-and-more/)